# How to remove project name in url in Jboss?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jboss, jboss7.x

My application is running fine with this url:
http://localhost:8291/projectName/index.html.

But I want to run my project with http://localhost:8291.

I tried following configuration changes in `standalone.xml` file in 
`jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\standalone\configuration\standalone.xml`

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:web:1.1" default-virtual-server="default-host" native="false">
        <connector name="http" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="http" socket-binding="http"/>
        <virtual-server name="default-host" enable-welcome-root="false">
            <alias name="localhost"/>
            <alias name="example.com"/>
        </virtual-server>
    </subsystem>
```

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure if you have found the solution or not but following might solve your problem.
I am assuming that your are deploying war file. 
In your Web Application folder as in screen shot create jboss-web.xml and add following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-web>
   <context-root>/</context-root>
</jboss-web>
```

[image]